# Raspbian can ssh/ping Me I can't

Tags: ssh, lan, ping, raspbian

Very strange problem here. On my LAN, there are a Raspbian and my PC, both connected to a router/ADSL.

Raspbian can ping/ssh me. But I can't from my PC toward the Raspbian. My PC is a Fedora 23 x64bit. I disabled iptables, SELinux on my PC. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Very newbie mistake!

The Raspbian was on a different netmask: `255.255.255.0`

And my PC wa on `255.255.255.0`

Comment: the netmasks you write are the same....